# Unable to get notification via Azure service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, azure, notifications, push

I have a phonegap ios app that I am trying to set up for push notifications. I am not a programmer, so please bear with me. I did everything in Microsoft azure's site and generated this script:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    request.execute();
    // Set timeout to delay the notification, to provide time for the
    // app to be closed on the device to demonstrate push notifications
    setTimeout(function() {
        push.apns.send(null, {
            alert: "Alert: " + item.text,
            payload: {
            inAppMessage: "Update: '" + item.text + "'"
            }
        });
    }, 2500);
}
```

My question is simple. What do I do with this script? I have set up an asp.net form to update the database, but nothing happens when I add any data.

Comment: You must also configure the APNS service as well - this requires you to setup an Apple developer account and configure certificates to allow your Mobile Service to connect to APNS and send push notifications to registered devices.

Answer (score 0):

The script, you have shown, is generated by Azure Mobile Service, JS backed service ( node js). So Azure Mobile service code ( which you have posted) signifies that, following script will be executed for every DB insert/update/delete - you need to figure out from where you got it. Following is the sample from my setup  ( for me , it is for `insert` operation to DB)

[image]

This means, it will execute the insert DB request, then it will sent notification to apple using `push.apns.send`.

Assumption: for your case, script corresponds to `insert` operation.

So to make it work, you need to invoke Azure Mobile Service , so that particularly this script will be executed and notification will be sent.

And if you directly insert to database using Asp.net form, this script will not be executed and notification won't be send.